# IOS Swift what am I messing up on in my UIView adding a subview

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiview, wkwebview

I have a UIView and set constraints on it as the image below shows . When I open it in the simulator it works correctly . The problem comes when I try and add a WKWEBview to display a video and add the subview . I want the video to take the dimensions of the UIView but the video looks extra small and the UIView looks like it shrinks . How can I fix that so that the video takes the full dimensions of the UIView . As you can see from the constraints it set to trail and leading and the video is not taking up that width even though it is large enough . The only thing I can think of for fixing this is adding a

addChildViewController(ViewController)

however the WKWebview does not have a Controller any suggestions would be great .

```
class ExampleTable: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var newView: UIView!
    var myWKWEBVIEW: WKWebView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
         myWKWEBVIEW?.uiDelegate = self
        guard let movieURL = URL(string: "my video url")
            else { return }
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
        webConfiguration.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = .audio

        myWKWEBVIEW = WKWebView(frame: newView.frame,configuration: webConfiguration)

        newView.addSubview(myWKWEBVIEW!)

          DispatchQueue.main.async (execute: { () -> Void in
            self.myWKWEBVIEW?.loadHTMLString("<video  height=\"\(self.newView.frame.height)\" width=\"\(self.newView.frame.width)\" muted=\"muted\"  autoplay=\"autoplay\"   src=\"\(movieURL)\" playsinline/>", baseURL: nil)


          })

    }

}
```

My constraints

[image]

How it looks with no addsubview

[image: This is how it looks with no add subview]
How it looks when I add subview to display video

[image: how it looks with add subview]

Comment: What frame are you getting in newView.frame in the viewDidLoad method? And what if you will use newView.bounds as a frame for your mkWebView?

Comment: I am getting the frame (0.0, 59.0, 375.0, 196.0) . I just used newView.bounds but still getting the same small video

Comment: Yes, but now it should be aligned correctly at the very top. I'm not sure if it will work but try to multiply your width and height values by two in the loadHTMLString. If it will fit your newView it means that you need to multiply it by two for a non retina screens an by three for retina ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check the below code :

```
myWKWEBVIEW = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x:0,y:0), size: newView.frame.size),configuration: webConfiguration)
```